# How to type a bigger $\oplus$

Tags: symbols

Please let me know if already asked, but How to type a bigger `$\oplus$` symbol?

I've tried `$\mathlarger{\oplus}$` but it returns: `\mathlarger⊕`

Sorry for been unclear, I am looking for an "Oplus" "bigger" than the "bigoplus".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the `bigoplus` which is probably what you are after.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
  \bigoplus \oplus 
\] 

\end{document}
```

> [image]

**Edit:**

After adding the last line of your question. If you need something arbitrarily large, you can use some other options. Here are two options using `\mathlarger` and `\scalebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}    % for \mathlarger to work
\usepackage{graphicx}   % for \scalebox to work
\begin{document}

 \[
    x+y=z \leftrightarrow \vcenter{\hbox{$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\oplus}}}}$}}
 \]
 %
 \newcommand{\Oplus}{\ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{5}{$\oplus$}}}}}
 \[
    x+y=z \leftrightarrow \Oplus \bigoplus
 \]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: You are too quick :P

Comment: Only sometimes `;-)`.

Comment: Only when it matters :)

Comment: Sorry, no mean to offense: I knew that $\bigoplus$ worked,
 but I was looking for a "bigger" oplus (upvoted anyway)

Comment: @LowGPA -- No offense at all, the question wasn't clear before you added the last line. I updated the answer. You still didn't show us why `\mathlarger` didn't work for you. You didn't provide a MWE, so as one can give you a precise answer.